# sap.ui.table not showing data

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am new to SAPUI5. Currently I am trying to create a simple app, showing a table based reporting with data from an SAP-system (odata). I use the SAP Web IDE as environment.

In the first attempt, I used the standard control sap.m.table. The worked fine for me. Now I wanted to use a simple sort function for my columns. Therefore I changed to sap.ui.table (seems a bit better for that need).

Starting the application, only the header part is showing (title) but my table doesn't appaer.
Debugging the apploication shows me correct data binding. Variable oTable gets the data, that is in variable oJsonModel.
What is missing for showing my table and why? The console in Chrome doesn't throw any error.

My application consists of one xml-view:

```
<mvc:View xmlns="sap.ui.table" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified" xmlns:m="sap.m"
xmlns:c="sap.ui.core" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" controllerName="Z_HCM_CICO_REP_2.controller.zbkTable">
        <m:Page title="{i18n>appTitle}" showHeader="true">
            <m:content>
                <Table id="zbkTable" rows="{/TimeEntrySet}">
                    <columns>
                        <Column id="pernr" sortProperty="pernr">
                            <m:Label text="{i18n>pernr}" textAlign="Center"/>
                            <template>
                                <m:Text text="{Pernr}"/>
                            </template>
                        </Column>
                        <Column id="ename" sortProperty="ename">
                            <m:Label text="{i18n>ename}" textAlign="Center"/>
                            <template>
                                <m:Text text="{Name}"/>
                            </template>
                        </Column>
                        <Column id="date" sortProperty="date">
                            <m:Label text="{i18n>date}" textAlign="Center"/>
                            <template>
                                <m:Text text="{Ldate}"/>
                            </template>
                        </Column>
                        <Column id="time" sortProperty="time">
                            <m:Label text="{i18n>time}" textAlign="Center"/>
                            <template>
                                <m:Text text="{Ltime}"/>
                            </template>
                        </Column>
                        <Column id="satza" sortProperty="satza">
                            <m:Label text="{i18n>satza}" textAlign="Center"/>
                            <template>
                                <m:Text text="{Ddtext}"/>
                            </template>
                        </Column>
                        <Column id="note" sortProperty="note">
                            <m:Label text="{i18n>note}" textAlign="Center"/>
                            <template>
                                <m:Text text="{NoticeText}"/>
                            </template>
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                </Table>

            </m:content>
        </m:Page>
```

My controller coding is as follows:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/table/SortOrder",
    "sap/ui/model/Sorter"
], function(Controller, SortOrder, Sorter) {
    "use strict";

return Controller.extend("Z_HCM_CICO_REP_2.controller.zbkTable", {

    /**
     * Called when a controller is instantiated and its View controls (if available) are already created.
     * Can be used to modify the View before it is displayed, to bind event handlers and do other one-time initialization.
     * @memberOf Z_HCM_CICO_REP_2.view.zbkTable
     */
    onInit: function() {
        //load cicos
        var oJsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        var oView = this.getView();
        var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
        var oTable = oView.byId("zbkTable");
        oTable.setModel(oJsonModel);
        // var that = this;

        oModel.read("/TimeEntrySet", {
            success: function(oData, oResponse) {
                oJsonModel.setData(oData);
                var aTimeList = oJsonModel.getData().results;
                $.each(aTimeList, function(index, value) {

                });
                //that.getOwnerComponent().setModel(oJsonModel);
            },
            error: function(oError) {

            }
        });
        oView.setModel(oJsonModel);
        //this.getOwnerComponent().setModel(oJsonModel);
        //oTable.bindItems("/TimeEntrySet");

        //Initial sorting
        var oDateColumn = oView.byId("date");
        //oView.byId("zbkTable").sort(oDateColumn, SortOrder.Ascending);
    }
});
```

My component coding is:

```
sap.ui.generic.app.AppComponent.extend("Z_HCM_CICO_REP_2.Component", {
metadata: {
    "manifest": "json"
    }
});

sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/ui/Device"
], function(UIComponent, Device) {
    "use strict";
return UIComponent.extend("Z_HCM_CICO_REP_2.Component", {

    /**
     * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
     * @public
     * @override
     */
    init: function() {
        // call the base component's init function
        UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

        var oResourceModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
            bundleName: "Z_HCM_CICO_REP_2.i18n.i18n"
        });
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oResourceModel, "i18n");

        //load cicos
        var sServiceUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZHCM_CICO_REP_SRV/";
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, true);
        this.setModel(oModel);
    }
});
```

thanks in advance and best regards

Christian

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read all your code, but you are defining your OData model in your component and then creating another JSON model in your controller. The JSON Model (the one set to the Table and the view) has the data you read 'inside /TimeEntrySet', therefore I guess there is not '/TimeEntrySet' node inside it. Just the children nodes. So the binding your are doing in your 'rows="/TimeEntrySet"' can't be resolved.

I think you don't need to replicate your data creating a JSON model in your controller. You should be able to access your OData model you define in the component.

Could you please delete all your code in the 'onInit()' function and try again?

Comment: Hi and thanks you for your explanation. I thought about the same, defining the model twice but wasn't really sure if thats incorrect or not. I commented all the coding in the onInit-function, but result is the same (empty content/no table).

Answer (score 0):

Actually Rafael's answer is true. Because data should be sorted on server side, not client side. This way you would not need a json model. But anyway in addition to Rafaels answer, this should do the trick :

```
oModel.read("/TimeEntrySet", {
        success: function(oData, oResponse) {
            oJsonModel.setProperty("/TimeEntrySet",oData.results);
```

Your row binding should work now .

Comment: Hi and thank you for the new coding. I implemented it and it seems to work correctly. oJsonModel now holds the TimeEntrySet in the oData-part. Content is still empty (no table is shown). What is missing? Do I have to bind the data to my view zbkTable with the bindRows-method?

Comment: debug your code and look at the callback function "success". there may be a child node under oData. like "results".

Comment: remember we need an array to set "TimeEntrySet" of our json model. So we're searching for an array under our OData response.

Comment: In callback function success, the array lies in results. After giving it to oJsonModel, the array is holded inside oData --> TimeEntrySet --> results. I tried the following line: oTable.bindRows(oJsonModel.getProperty("/TimEntrySet")); That does end in an error that says: "Cannot read property 'template' of undefined sap.ushell.renderers.fiori2.Shell.controller".

Comment: I've edited my answer. So did you try it like this way? Bc you should not need "bindRows" method.

Comment: I changed the coding, based on your update. A table is still not shown. oData in variable oJsonModel now holds an array called TimeEntrySet. So this seems to work correctly. Something, I think very simple, is missing. What could that be?

Comment: oh I see your models don't have names. Can you try giving a name to your jsonModel when setting it to your view and use it in your table like rows="{yourModelName>/TimeEntrySet}"

Comment: I am not really sure about setting the name to my oJsonModel. Do I have to use the setJSON-method (because there is a variable called name in it)? I tried .setJSON({name : "myModel"}). That had no Impact on the name variable in oJsonModel. I added "myModel" in my XML view as you mentioned: rows="{myModel>/TimeEntrySet}"

Comment: use oTable.setModel(oJsonModel, "yourmodelname") instead of oTable.setModel(oJsonModel)

Comment: Hi, that seems to work correctly as well. Now I have an instance of "myModel" in my oTable. In this instance "myModel" I can see oData with the filled array TimeEntrySet. But as you can imagine...there is still no table shown. I can see the Header with the title and the border of the app, but no table.

Comment: my last shot: you updated your Column templates as well, didn't you? Like <m:Text text="{myModel>Name}"/>

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the issue. There is still no error and no table. Do I only have to update the m:Text-elements? What about the column-elements?

Comment: Actually all of them but when you change just one, table should appear with just one column filled with data. I don't know, I guess we miss something and it's probably basic as hell.

Comment: Anyway thank you so much for helping. *thumbs up* Must be something really basic...